# Method description for the QGIS function: concave hull (k-nearest neighbor)

Tags: references, concave-hull

Im using the concave hull (k-nearest neigbor) function from QGIS (not the plugin). When clicking on this function there is a small but not really detailed description of the method. I was wondering where I can find a more detailed description, such as a literature source. Is there anything on github or another website where I can find it?

Comment: Did you check the source code?

Comment: Where do I find the source code?

Comment: I'd start at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/KNearestConcaveHull.py